# Multiline string issue

Tags: javascript, jslint

jsLint is not reporting an error. But when I post it into jsbin.com I get a warning. Also if I search on the warning 'Bad line break before "+"' I see people trying to turn this option off in jsLint.

snippet :

```
var some_html = " "
    + "<div>"
    +     "<span></span>"
    + "</div>";
```

Is there a problem with defining/assigning a string this way?

Comment: Why do you `$`-prefix your non-jQuery variables?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster That was bug. This was originally copied from a php document and then adapted. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code, jsbin.com is just expecting it to be written like this:

```
var some_html = " " +
    "<div>" +
    "<span></span>" +
    "</div>";
```

for some reason.  I'd just ignore the warning.

Incidentally writing it with the `+` on the same line as the string it's extending, like above, is also accepted by JSLint.  So if you want your code to pass in both without warnings, you might want to stick to doing it like that.

The fact that JSLint doesn't mind the way you wrote it, but people have written about it, could be down to JSLint getting rid of this warning (although I'm just guessing!).

Comment: There is something wrong with the code.  It's not guaranteed to work.  By putting the `+` on the next line, you're making the current line subject to semicolon insertion by the JavaScript interpreter.  It may work in one JavaScript engine, but fail in another.

Comment: @DominicMitchell, I wasn't aware of that - can you provide an example browser / JavaScript engine in which this is the case?

Comment: The [EMCA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (v. 5.1 at least) gives specific details of when semi-colons can be automatically inserted (section 7.9).  I don't think this is (should be!) implementation specific.

Comment: Don't exclude the possibility of non-conformant engines.  e.g. the issue of trailing commas is different in IE compared to all other browsers.

Comment: So is there any JS engine in which the code in this question is a problem - or is this just a theoretical problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
var some_html = [
    '<div>',
    '<span></span>',
    '</div>'
].join('');
```

what this does it place your broken strings in an array, and join them without a delimiter. it will return a string. I think this will pass.